# probability that a random point (X,Y) will fall into the ring

Tags: probability

Random variables $X$, $Y$ are independent and normally
distributed with $M[X]= M[Y] =0$, $D[X] = D[Y]=1$. Find the probability
that a random point $(X,Y)$ will fall into
the ring
$\{(x,y): 2\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}  \leq 3)\}$.

I think we can find the density function $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)}$
and then substitute the area of the circle into the integral. Please tell me if I think correctly.

Comment: Integrate the density function over the ring using polar coordinates.

Comment: Thanks you, i decided this problem

Answer (score 2):

Using polars,  your probability is

$$\underbrace{\int_2^3 r e^{-r^2/2}dr}_{\text{immediate integral}}\times\underbrace{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta}_{=1}=\left[-e^{-r^2/2}\right]_{r=2}^{r=3}=e^{-2}-e^{-9/2}\approx 12.42\%$$